# What is the meaning of this line from the prophecy of the Dwarf Ghost Lady at High Heart?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

The dwarf ghost lady at High Heart prophesies for the Brotherhood Without Banners and Arya. 
Among passages about the deaths of kings, she says, "I dreamt of a maid at a feast with purple serpents in her hair, venom dripping from their fangs. And later I dreamt that maid again, slaying a savage giant in a castle built of snow"

It's likely these two sentences are about one person. We have seen

> Sansa's hairnet of poison crystals accounts for the purple serpents

In a later scene, we see something hinting at the second sentence, but the symbolism is less clear.

> Sansa builds a snowcastle at the Eyrie, but Robert knocks it over. Is he the figurative giant? If so, how was she predicted to 'slay' him? Was it by slapping him?

Comment: Robert said that his doll was a giant and Sansa ripped the head off the doll.

Comment: Ah, i must have been mixing book with show.

Comment: Many people believe the 'Giant' to be **[Petyr Baelish](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Petyr_Baelish)**, remember that his mother is Braavosi, and his sigil was the **[Titan of Braavos](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Titan_of_Braavos)**. He also is an economic and political "giant", especially for such a man of "small" stature and birth!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exact quote from Robert is:

> "It's not so great." The boy knelt before the gatehouse. "Look, here comes a giant to knock it down." He stood his doll in the snow and moved it jerkily.

Sansa then

> tries to grab his hand but catches the doll instead, ripping of it's head and "slaying" it, so to speak.

That is pretty much exactly what the prophecy stated, if you take it literally. It will be interesting to see if there is anything more to the prophecy over the course of the next books...